# how can i save a json data from a certain url in angular 6

Tags: node.js, json, angular, mongodb

I want to save a json data from a url inside my mongodb in my angular app ,how can i perform that

**Here is my json data format from a url**

```
[
  {
    "registrationno": "INF/E/2016/0024",
    "firstname": "Mariam",
    "lastname": "Manjenje",
    "amount": 10000,
    "reason": "lost the book"
  },
  {
    "registrationno": "IWR/D/2016/0024",
    "firstname": "Mariam",
    "lastname": "Wamigomba",
    "amount": 0,
    "reason": "none"
  },
  {
    "registrationno": "FOR/E/2016/0024",
    "firstname": "Rebecca",
    "lastname": "Musa",
    "amount": 0,
    "reason": "none"
  },
  {
    "registrationno": "inf/d/2017/0008",
    "firstname": "Rebecca",
    "lastname": "Musa",
    "amount": 50000,
    "reason": "lost the book:Title:Quntum Physics"
  }
]
```

**here is how i get the data from the url**

```
 getAllStudents() {
    this.http.get<{students: Student[]}>('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1cr428').subscribe(result => {
      this.updateStudents.next(result.students);
      console.log(result);

    });

  }
```

**How can i save that data in my mongodb**

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is using GET request to an API to retrieve some data, this API has function implemented to query the database, extract the data and return JSON.
If you want to populate your own database you have to build your own API which can handle simple CRUD functions, you can't just interact with your database directly from your frontend.
Nodejs and Flask framework for python are in my opinion 2 of the most easiest way to do it.

Comment: i want to save it in my mongodb using nodejs how can i perform that brother

Comment: I suggest you to watch some tutorials on youtube, it's really simple, just look for Expressjs + node.js + Mongodb.

Comment: thyanks brother